# Activate Python venv from everywhere

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-venv

I'm using Python [venv](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/venv.html) as virtual environments manager on Windows.

When I want to activate an environment, I find it a little bit frustrating changing the directory back and forth to activate the environment and return to the current directory: Suppose that I'm in the `C:\users\me\my_dir` directory, and my environment is in `C:\users\me\.venvs\my_env`, I have to do the following:

```sh
> cd C:\users\me\venvs\my_env\Scripts
> activate
> cd C:\users\me\my_dir
```

For that, I want to know if there is some shortcut to activate an environment directly from the current directory, something like this (suppose that I'm in `my_dir` directory):

```
> python venv --activate my_env
```

Comment: While in `my_dir` just do `C:\users\me\venvs\my_env\Scripts\activate`

Comment: just give the exact or relative path of activate or put that in bashrc

Comment: @rdas thank you, that's an abbreviation. But I still have to remember (or copy-paste) the entire ``venv``'s path.

Comment: You can set it as a alias using doskey in CMD.